# Stop react show more button scrolling to bottom of content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the follwing todo component. It's purpose is to show 10 todos, and when `More` is clicked, show 10 more.

```
const ToDoList = ({ todos }) => {
  const [viewCount, setViewCount] = useState(1);

  const handleViewMore = (e) => {
    setViewCount(viewCount + 1);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {
          todos.slice(0, viewCount * 10)
            .map((todo, index) => (
              <ToDo {...todo} key={index} />
            ))
        }
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleViewMore}>More</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The issue is when `More` is clicked, the extra todos are added however the windows scroll is still with the button, below the added todos.

For example, if 10 todos gives `window.scrollY` of 1000, when I click `More`, `winodw.scrollY` is now 2000, but I want it to remain at 1000 to allow the user to scroll through the next 10.

It's worth noting this does not happen if I change the button to an `a` or `span`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Here is a codesandbox version of the issue - https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-snowflake-wl2h8?file=/src/App.js

I have included a `More Broken` button as well as a `More Expected` span. I'd like the button to behave as the span does.

Comment: Basically you want the scroll position to be on the first item of the new 10 todos?

Comment: adding a interactive example would help people answer your question; `codesandbox` or something like that

Comment: @bertdida exactly yes.

Comment: scroll doesn't change in your example, it remains 0 after "More" is clicked

Comment: @dulebov.artem please try now

Comment: @amcquaid still the same

Comment: @dulebov.artem if you scroll down to the bottom, to index 14, and click more, for me it adds the extra, up to 29, but keeps you scrolled to the bottom of the page

Comment: @amcquaid what browser do you use?

Comment: @dulebov.artem chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange, it is some new behavior that happens only in the latest version of chrome (85, maybe 84).
All the other browsers remain the scroll position in your case.
It might be a bug or a feature, not sure, meanwhile you can

change `onClick` to `onMouseDown`
and

```
  const handleViewMore = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()  
    setViewCount(viewCount + 1);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could maitain the current scroll postion before click more button and scroll back to it

```
const [viewCount, setViewCount] = useState(1)
const [currentScrollTop, setCurrentScrollTop] = useState(0)

const handleViewMore = (e) => {
  setCurrentScrollTop(document.documentElement.scrollTop)
  setViewCount(viewCount + 1)
}

useEffect(() => {
  window.scrollTo(0, currentScrollTop)
}, [currentScrollTop])
```

Codesandbox link

[image: Edit elastic-flower-qtxv8]

Comment: I'd like it to remain at the positon it was before the More button is clicked, not scroll to the more button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}, [viewCount])
```